# Java multiple completablefuture

Tags: java

I wrote the following snipet code within Cumulocity platform.

> runForTenant

must be in a separate thread. What is your an opinion about my code. is there any need for optimization? Thanks

```
LinkedList<CompletableFuture<Void>> asyncThreads = new LinkedList<CompletableFuture<Void>>();
        CompletableFuture<Iterable<ManagedObjectRepresentation>> response = new CompletableFuture<>();

        subscriptions.runForEachTenant(() -> {
            String tenant = subscriptions.getTenant();
            asyncThreads.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                subscriptions.runForTenant(tenant, () -> {
                    Iterable<ManagedObjectRepresentation> objects = inventoryApi
                            .getManagedObjectsByFilter(customInventoryFilter).get().allPages();
                    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(objects)) {
                        response.complete(objects);
                    }

                });
            })); // end of runAsync()
        });

        boolean allThreadsAreDone = true;
        do { // until all threads are done ...
            try {
                return response.get(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // wait for first result
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                // device with UUID Not found in time

                // check all threads are done/closed/stopped in all fashions
                allThreadsAreDone = true;
                for (int i = 0; allThreadsAreDone && i < asyncThreads.size(); i++) {
                    allThreadsAreDone = asyncThreads.get(i).isDone();
                }
            } catch (ExecutionException execExc) {
                logger.error("Error on lookup: " + execExc.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (InterruptedException interExc) {
                logger.error("Error on lookup: " + interExc.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        } while (!allThreadsAreDone);
```

I want to optimize the last path of the code:

```
boolean allThreadsAreDone = true;
    do { // until all threads are done ...
        try {
            return response.get(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // wait for first result
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            // device with UUID Not found in time

            // check all threads are done/closed/stopped in all fashions
            allThreadsAreDone = true;
            for (int i = 0; allThreadsAreDone && i < asyncThreads.size(); i++) {
                allThreadsAreDone = asyncThreads.get(i).isDone();
            }
        } catch (ExecutionException execExc) {
            logger.error("Error on lookup: " + execExc.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException interExc) {
            logger.error("Error on lookup: " + interExc.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    } while (!allThreadsAreDone);
```

Comment: What does `subscriptions::runForEachTenant` do? Executes a `Runnable`? Naming suggests it should execute a `Function` or a `Consumer` of `tenant`.

Comment: @AndreyLebedenko yes, it executes Runnable

Answer (score 1):

I have one advice, but since the code is not compiling, it's a bit hard to make a proper review.

Instead of using an `java.util.LinkedList`, I suggest that you use the `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` to handle the threads and use it to check the end of the threads.

```java
        ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        CompletableFuture<Iterable<ManagedObjectRepresentation>> response = new CompletableFuture<>();

        subscriptions.runForEachTenant(() -> {
            String tenant = subscriptions.getTenant();
            taskExecutor.execute(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                subscriptions.runForTenant(tenant, () -> {
                    Iterable<ManagedObjectRepresentation> objects = inventoryApi
                            .getManagedObjectsByFilter(customInventoryFilter).get().allPages();

                    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(objects)) {
                        response.complete(objects);
                    }

                });
            }));
        });

        taskExecutor.shutdown();
        try {
            taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

        // The threads are finished.
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice

Comment: If the code does not compile it's off topic and shouldn't be answered

Comment: it is not possible to show you the whole code ;)

Comment: Calling `taskExecutor.execute(CompletableFuture.runAsync(` does not make much sense, since `CompletableFuture.runAsync` in this case we use ForkJoin internally. Instead pass an executor as a second parameter of `CompletableFuture.runAsync` itself. The number of threads in executor is also an open question. Also, in case of multiple parallel calls to this block, it may quickly end up in resource starvation, due to multiple executors competing for processor. Therefore it is better to pass an executor as a parameter from outside of the block, and don't shut it down.

Comment: Also taskExecutor.execute requires Runnable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 1):

The second loop `do...while` can be replaced by

```
    asyncThreads.forEach(cf -> cf.join()); // blocks until all CompletableFutures join in any order.
```

Though those are not threads, per say, they are CompletableFutures.